# Javascript does not run from MVC Partial View

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, partial-views

The below RenderPartial displays a partial view from Html.BeginForm() method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("abc", "xyz", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", @onsubmit = "return onFormSubmit(this);" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div id="ApplyForFormDetails" class="form">
                    @{ Html.RenderPartial(Model.CurrentForm.ViewName, Model.CurrentForm); }
                </div>
                 <button type="submit" id="btnNextLoad" name="action" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="enableDefaultTrue: enableNextButton"> </button>
            }
```

I have the below javascript function at the partial view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var model = @(Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, new JsonSerializerSettings {ContractResolver = new ExcludePropertiesContractResolver()})));
        model["A1"] = '@ViewData["A1"]';
        model["A2"] = '@ViewData["A2"]';
        model["A3"] = '@ViewData["A3"]';
        var viewModel = new ABC.SelectABC(model);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
</script>
```

When the button id="btnNextLoad" is clicked it displayed the partial view content and then the javascript is getting hit.

Is there a way to run the javascript method before displaying the partial view content ?

Comment: Give the partial view content style `display:none` and have the script unhide it?

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: Though if we add display:none, the partial view loading will happen anyway right ?